# Yii2: Customize PieChart colors using GoogleChart Widget

Tags: php, yii2, pie-chart

I have tried this code to change the color:

```
<?php
    echo GoogleChart::widget(array('visualization' => 'PieChart',
        'data' => array(
            array('Task', 'All Statuses'),
            //   array('Picked Up', (int) $all_vehicle['picked_up']),
            array('Car on Way', (int) $all_vehicle['car_on_way']),
            array('Shipped', (int) $all_vehicle['shipped']),
            array('On Hand', (int) $all_vehicle['on_hand']),
        ),
        'options' => array('title' => 'All','width' => 442, 'height' => 400, 'pieHole' => 0.4, 'seriesColors' => [ "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000" ])
    ));
?>
```

Using this  array to change the color

```
seriesColors' => [ "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000" ])
```

Comment: if you can help

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: I have spended more then 2 hours to find the solution but the avaliale solution not working in php .So whats does its mean to simly " "it doesn't work"....Sir i have mention the detail code and the array i am using...so its enough for solution @TobySpeight

Comment: You haven't explained what kind of "not working" you get.  Do you get any error messages?  Do you get some output that's not what you expect?  (If so, show the actual and expected output so we can see what's wrong).  Providing this extra information will make it easier for for someone to help you find the problem (I'm sorry that I can't, but I don't know any of the technologies here).

Comment: things should be taken lightly Sajid after all he came here to help you out and is asking the right thing that you should add the specific error or exceptions, @TobySpeight I apologize on sajid's behalf i hope you dont mind.

Comment: Sajid can you provide the link to the exact widget  you are using.

Comment: @TobySpeight m sorry!

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-google-chart/

Comment: The array i have passed is working here in javascript but not in php as i mention above @MuhammadOmerAslam https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476187/jqplot-pie-chart-change-pie-slice-colors

Comment: added an answer see if that helps out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the option `color` rather than `seriesColor` as the option for the plugin see [**`DOCS`**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts). so change your widget code to the below

```
<?php
    echo GoogleChart::widget(array('visualization' => 'PieChart',
        'data' => array(
            array('Task', 'All Statuses'),
            //   array('Picked Up', (int) $all_vehicle['picked_up']),
            array('Car on Way', (int) $all_vehicle['car_on_way']),
            array('Shipped', (int) $all_vehicle['shipped']),
            array('On Hand', (int) $all_vehicle['on_hand']),
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'title' => 'All', 
            'width' => 442, 
            'height' => 400, 
            'pieHole' => 0.4, 
            'colors'=> ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']
        )
    ));
?>
```